# Postgres - Update Performance degraded

Tags: postgresql

Can someone please help assist in identifying why below statement which used to take 2 hours is not taking 6 hours without volume increase being a factor.

```
with P as 
(SELECT DISTINCT CD.CASE_DETAIL_ID, SVL.SERVICE_LEVEL_ID\n       
FROM report_fct CD LEFT JOIN SERVICE_LEVEL SVL ON SVL.ORDER_TYPE_CD =   CD.ORDER_TYPE_CD\n                                                            
AND SVL.SOURCE_ID = CD.SOURCE_ID\n                                                  AND SVL.AREA_ID = CD.HQ_AREA_ID\n                                                   AND SVL.CATEGORY_ID = CD.CATEGORY_ID\n                                              AND SVL.STATE_CD = CD.CUST_STATE\n       
WHERE CD.LINE_OF_BIZ = 'CLOTH'\n       
AND CD.HQ_AREA_ID is NOT NULL\n       
AND CD.SOURCE_ID is NOT NULL\n       
AND CD.CATEGORY_ID is NOT NULL\n       
AND CD.CUST_STATE is NOT NULL)\n
update report_fct rpt\n
set service_level_id = P.service_level_id\n
from P\n
where rpt.case_detail_id = P.case_detail_id;"}


CREATE TABLE report_fct 
...
..
case_detail_id bigint NOT NULL,
...



CREATE INDEX report_fct _ix1
ON report_fct USING btree
(case_detail_id)
TABLESPACE pg_default;


CREATE INDEX report_fct _ix2
    ON report_fct  USING btree
    (insert_dt)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

One doubt I have is whether statistics can be skewed on this table which is resulting in degradation.

```
relname       inserts      updates  deletes live_tuples dead_tupes  last autovacuum last autoanalyze
report_fct  262746347   5387849450  0           2473523    3573914  5/19/20 3:38    5/19/20 1:13


EXPLAIN:
"Update on report_fct rpt  (cost=24847.47..27881.35 rows=415 width=3772)"
"  CTE p"
"    ->  Unique  (cost=24844.02..24847.05 rows=405 width=16)"
"          ->  Sort  (cost=24844.02..24845.03 rows=405 width=16)"
"                Sort Key: cd.case_detail_id, svl.service_level_id"
"                ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.41..24826.48 rows=405 width=16)"
"                      ->  Seq Scan on report_fct cd  (cost=0.00..21915.21 rows=405 width=44)"
"                            Filter: ((hq_area_id IS NOT NULL) AND (source_id IS NOT NULL) AND (category_id IS NOT NULL) AND (cust_state IS NOT NULL) AND ((line_of_biz)::text = 'CLOTH'::text))"
"                      ->  Index Scan using service_level_unq on service_level svl  (cost=0.41..7.18 rows=1 width=45)"
"                            Index Cond: ((area_id = cd.hq_area_id) AND ((order_type_cd)::text = (cd.order_type_cd)::text) AND (source_id = cd.source_id) AND (state_cd = (cd.cust_state)::bpchar) AND (category_id = cd.category_id))"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.41..3034.30 rows=415 width=3772)"
"        ->  CTE Scan on p  (cost=0.00..8.10 rows=405 width=56)"
"        ->  Index Scan using report_fct_ix1 on report_fct rpt  (cost=0.41..7.46 rows=1 width=3724)"
"              Index Cond: (case_detail_id = p.case_detail_id)"
```

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for the slow execution.

Comment: Unable to run EXPLAIN with ANALYZE as we cant run the update on production adhoc. Edited post to include output of EXPLAIN.

Comment: Do it in a transaction that you roll back afterwards. Without good diagnostics the question cannot be answered.

Comment: Hi Laurenz, the update takes 3 hours to run .. much as i myself want to see the analyze it does not seem possible to get this right now. I would appreciate it if you have any insight on the query ad data i have provided.

Comment: Can one `report_fct` be associated with more than one `service_level` in the join?

Comment: Due to application wide degradation in performance, we rebooted the Aurora Postgres instance and ran manual VACUUM ANALYZE. This returned all queries back to normal performance. If anyone has any insight into why these actions would have helped, specifically why auto vacuum and analyze which were updating these tables was not helping as we suspect, please update.